# Unexpected symbol error for lm_model addition

Tags: r, statistics

I've been trying to run this code:

```
lm_model <- lm(Calories ~ Sodium + Carbohydrates + Protein + Caffeine + Dietary Fiber, 
               data = Starbucks)
```

but I keep getting

> Error: unexpected symbol in "lm_model <- lm(Calories ~ Sodium + Carbohydrates + Protein + Caffeine + Dietary Fiber"

Comment: `Dietary Fiber` is not a valid name.  You need to rename it or quote with backticks `\`Dietary Fiber\``.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting that issue because the column name 'Dietary Fiber' is two words

To fix it, find out exactly what it's called in your data (e.g. run `colnames(Starbucks)`) and look for the column there and make sure you name it exactly the same

If the `Dietary Fiber` column name does indeed contain a space, you can surround it with the backtick character (i.e. ` ) so R knows to treat it as one single column name

#### Example

Here's an example of using `lm()` with a column whose names contain a space

```
a <- iris[1:10, c(1:2)]

# This works
lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = a)

# But what if we try the same thing with a space in the column name?
colnames(a)[2] <- "Sepal Width"

# Now it errors
lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = a)
# Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Sepal.Width' not found

# To use lm() function with a column name that contains spaces, use the backtick
lm(Sepal.Length ~ `Sepal Width`, data = a)
```